# Imagemagick - split image and pipe to convert?

Tags: animation, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, mogrify

I wish to split and image and then turn it into an animated gif with a single command.

At the moment, I'm doing

```
mogrify -resize 200%x100% -crop 50%x100% image.jpg
```

Then I can do

```
convert -delay 25x100 -loop 0 image-0.jpg image-1.jpg movie.gif
```

Is there a way that I can pipe the output of mogrify to the input of convert?

I tried running

```
convert -delay 25x100 -loop 0 <(mogrify -crop 50%x100% m.jpg :-) test.gif
```

But it failed with the error

```
mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-bHWzk1Xl' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-mVXjCXLd' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
convert: missing an image filename `test.gif' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3011
```

Answer (score 0):

Close, but I think you're missing an extra '-'

Try :

`mogrify -resize 200%x200% -crop 50%x100% -delay 10 input.jpg | convert - -delay 25x100 -loop 0 input-0.jpg input-1.jpg output.gif`

This does throw an error, but works. It will also destroy the original, so you might want to use an output filename eg:

`mogrify -resize 200%x200% -crop 50%x100% -delay 10 -write output.jpg input.jpg | convert - -delay 25x100 -loop 0 output-0-0.jpg output-0-1.jpg output.gif`

This will also complain, but also works as you require.

Comment: Not quite what I need. I want to avoid writing the file name multiple times.  I don't always know what the file name is going to be, for example.